# Can not select child element using JQuery/CSS :nth-child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to update the `id` values of elements using JQuery/CSS selector dynamically by running a `for` loop.

What i want is when i **click on button** it runs the for loop and updates the `id` of `<div id='input_1' class="input row">` which is inside each `button_pro class`.

My issue is i cannot do so, i am **not able to select child as for loop executes and can not update my id** values.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kL5pngjc/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="button_pro">
    <div id='input_1' class="input row">
        <div class="input-field col s1">
            <input class="sno" type="text" name="Sr_1" value="1">
            <label for="Sr">Sr</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2">
            <input id="item_code" type="text" name="item_code_1" value="">
            <label for="item_code">Item Code</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="button_pro">
    <div id='input_1' class="input row">
        <div class="input-field col s1">
            <input class="sno" type="text" name="Sr_1" value="1">
            <label for="Sr">Sr</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2">
            <input id="item_code" type="text" name="item_code_1" value=" ">
            <label for="item_code">Item Code</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>       
<br>

<button>Click</button>
```

**JQuery/JavaScrit**

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var numof = $(".input").length;
        alert(numof);
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= numof; i++) 
        {
            $(".input:nth-child(" + i + ")").attr('id', 'input_' + i);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eq()`.

`:nth-child` will select the `nth` child. As your elements are not direct child, use `eq`.

```
$(".input").eq(i).attr('id', 'input_' + i);
```

Also, note that `eq` starts from zero, so you need to change the `for` loop.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kL5pngjc/5/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var numof = $(".input").length;
    alert(numof);
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= numof; i++) {
      $(".input:nth-child(" + i + ")").attr('id', 'input_' + i);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button_pro">
  <div id='input_1' class="input row">
    <div class="input-field col s1">
      <input class="sno" type="text" name="Sr_1" value="1">
      <label for="Sr">Sr</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2">
      <input id="item_code" type="text" name="item_code_1" value="">
      <label for="item_code">Item Code</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button_pro">
  <div id='input_1' class="input row">
    <div class="input-field col s1">
      <input class="sno" type="text" name="Sr_1" value="1">
      <label for="Sr">Sr</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2">
      <input id="item_code" type="text" name="item_code_1" value=" ">
      <label for="item_code">Item Code</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(function() {
            $('button').click(function() {                    
                var objs = $(".input");
                var numof = $(".input").length;
                alert(numof);
                /*
                var i;
                for (i = 1; i <= numof; i++) {
                $(".input:nth-child(" + i + ")").attr('id', 'input_' + i);
                }
                */
                $(objs).each(function(i, item) {                        
                    $('#' + item.id).attr('id', 'input_' + i);
                });
            });
        });
    });     //]]>
```